# Any quick/easy way to delete <version> tag from pom files?

Tags: maven, plugins

Is there a plugin or a tool that I can use to quickly delete all `<version>` tags from a pom defn?

I have a a few multi-module projects with some 50-80 modules, each with a `<version>` tag.  However, they each inherit from a common parent, so I would rather remove all `<version>` definitions in each module pom and have it inherit the version from the parent.

Search & Replace will obviously delete any tags in plugins, dependencies, etc.

Is there something that exists that will do this quickly for me instead?  For the moment, I find myself editing each file individually, which is time consuming.

Comment: not sure, that it's possible anyhow except for search&replace, because of pom.xml nature

Comment: If I had enough files to modify, I would attempt it with Groovy.  It has a XmlSlurper that makes working with XML files fairly simple.

Comment: Using Eclipse will show you a warnining if you overwrite the dependencyManager from parent and there you could use Quick-Fix in Eclipse. Groovy sounds also like an reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of head scratching, I came up with a fairly simple method.

Using the versions-maven-plugin, I was able to recursively go through each module in my application and set the version to some known string.  Then after that, it becomes an easy Search and Replace to remove that one string.

Ex:

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=9999_TO_DELETE_9999 -f {} \;
```

then it becomes a simple Search and Replace to delete the `<VERSION>9999_TO_DELETE_9999</VERSION>` string.

Care must be taken to exclude the parent pom from the find command otherwise it will update the parent pom version in all the modules as well.

Maybe not as elegant as Groovy, but fairly quick and easy.